# Long HDMI cable or Long USB 3.0 cable for my Sony Camcorder?

Tags: usb, hdmi, cable, camcorder

I am planning to install my Sony HDR camcorder for about 35 meters, away from my computer, I know it’s kinda crazy. I love my Sony camcorder and instead of buying a camcorder that has an SDI I still stick with my HDMI camcorder. I am using live streaming software for our Church, and planning to buy a Magewell XI100DUSB-HDMI USB Capture HDMI 3.0 HD Video Capture Dongle.

I know that both HDMI and USB cable has length limitations, my question is should I go for long HDMI cables? What should I do if I go for long HDMI cables? Also if I am going to install a long USB 3.0 cables, what shoud I do?

Comment: What do you expect from us? If you are out of specs for both cable types then there is no guarantee for either of them to work (with a good quality). Either move pc and camera closer,  either convert your signal to LAN / wifi.

Comment: Max lenght for USB is 5 meters. There are longer cables on the market, which may or may not work. Those are out of spec.

Comment: Since you are trying to do this for a church, you could pray for it to work.  But without a miracle, you will need an alternate approach.

Comment: Feel free to contact me for more pertinent info on church setups.

Answer (score 1):

Either try a USB extender (e.g. [Extron's](http://www.extron.com/product/product.aspx?id=usbextender) or [TrippLite's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003WO40V6)) or an HDMI extender (e.g. [Cable Matters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007K7P6GO) or [MilesTek](http://www.milestek.com/c-972-hdmi-over-cat5ecat6-extenders.aspx)) or move things closer.

Though I've no experience with these devices, I'd assume you'll get *some* signal degradation.

Comment: I've used Ethernet based extenders. that's what I would recommend. Or powered HDMI/USB.

Comment: The TrippLite's transmit only at USB2 FS (full speed 12Mbps) rate. The Extron can do up to HS USB2 (480Mbps). For USB3.0 you need to go with optical solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that HDMI or any other copper cables can help you with 35m distance. But for USB3 speed you can get an optical connection made by [Corning Communication](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dcomputers&field-keywords=Optical%20Cables%20by%20Corning%20USB%203.0). It will be pricey though for a 50m link.

EDIT: be aware that the Corning extension can't supply much power, so the device end must be self-powered (have a wall AC-DC adapter).